# Apache 2.4 and PHP-FPM Timeout resulting from something I can't find

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, timeout

So I'm looking to find the reason I keep getting timeouts on my Apache 2.4 server with PHP-FPM. Here's the error:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid ###] (70007)The timeout 
specified has expired:[client XXXXXXXX] AH01075 : 
Error dispatching request to:, referer: http://address
```

In the following config files, I have played with every timeout I show. I have two pools in fpm:

```
[www]
;user and group info and listening ip and such up here
access_log = /path/to/access.log
request_terminate_timeout = 15
php_admin_value[error_log] = /path/to/error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

and the second:

```
[app]
;user and group info and listening ip and such up here
access_log = /path/to/access.log
request_terminate_timeout = 300
php_admin_value[error_log] = /path/to/error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

and my php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
default_socket_timeout = 300
```

So then my Apache config:

```
Timeout 80 
<FilesMatch "^(some | names | of | files)\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://123.45.5.67:7891"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^!(some | names | of | files)\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://123.45.5.67:5432"
</FilesMatch>
```

Obviously there's a lot more in the httpd.conf, but no timeouts are specified (except for an unrelated ProxyPass set to 300 seconds). I have read this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270655/how-to-find-and-edit-apache-timeout, but I've checked our patches with `rpm -q --changelog httpd | less`, and there's a patch for that bug. The timeouts were also much more chaotic when I only had one pool. Anywhere from 24 seconds to 6.7 minutes (at 5Kb/s throttled upload speed; not a problem with the code, was purposefully testing). For a while it seemed like it was correlated with `request_terminate_timeout`, but that correlation died.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turns out that it had something to do with the throttle speed. It was so low that the request was timing out. I fixed that by changing the RequestReadTimeout:

`RequestReadTimeout header=20-120,MinRate=50 body=20,MinRate=50`

Note this is also helpful if traffic from users is going through a proxy or firewall before getting to your server. The time between the request and the data could be significant.

Comment: how did you figure it out? it worked for me too

Comment: @NabeelKhan Many days of reading documentation and a lot of tests. Reducing the values to very short timeouts and using very small files helped me figure out it was a firewall issue.